# Как сравнить два изображения в процентном соотношении?

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек

Есть два изображения, скажем "кнопка без фокуса" и "кнопка выделенная".

Есть эталонное изображение, как его сравнить с тестовым и желательно в процентном соотношении высчитать на сколько процентов оно сходно с эталонным?

Comment: Предположу, что вам нужно что-то вроде этого: http://robocraft.ru/blog/computervision/506.html

Answer (score 0):

Рисунок - это матрица. Поделив одну матрицу на другую вы получите некую разницу между ними. Как в этом случае определить % подобия, тут уже вам решать - зависит от задачи... Например, можно вычислить среднее значение в матрице полученной от деления.

```
import rasterio

with rasterio.open('/path/to/raster.tif', 'r') as ds:
    arr = ds.read()  # read all raster values

print(arr.shape)  # this is a 3D numpy array, with dimensions [band, row, col]
```

- в `scipy` еще был инструмент аналогичный